# Complete Series From Partial Series

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I'm struggling to come up with an answer to this problem and so hope to find some help here.
I have the following time series data table with missing entries:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT timestamp::timestamp, deviceid, eventcount
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'AAAAA', 1000 ),
    ( '2017-01-01 00:30:00', 'AAAAA', 1000 ),
    ( '2017-01-01 00:40:00', 'AAAAA', 1000 ),
    ( '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'BBBBB', 2000 ),
    ( '2017-01-01 00:10:00', 'BBBBB', 2000 ),
    ( '2017-01-01 00:50:00', 'BBBBB', 2000 )
  ) AS t(Timestamp, DeviceID, EventCount);
```

I need to generate from this a complete series i.e.

```
+---------------------+----------+------------+
|      Timestamp      | DeviceID | EventCount |
+---------------------+----------+------------+
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | AAAAA    |       1000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | AAAAA    |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | AAAAA    |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | AAAAA    |       1000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | AAAAA    |       1000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | AAAAA    |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | BBBBB    |       2000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | BBBBB    |       2000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | BBBBB    |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | BBBBB    |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | BBBBB    |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | BBBBB    |       2000 |
+---------------------+----------+------------+
```

I have tried generating a series of timestamps with an interval of 10 minutes and then left joining on the first table but what I end up with is this:

```
+---------------------+----------+------------+
|      Timestamp      | DeviceID | EventCount |
+---------------------+----------+------------+
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL     |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | NULL     |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | NULL     |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | NULL     |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | NULL     |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | NULL     |          0 |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | AAAAA    |       1000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | AAAAA    |       1000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | AAAAA    |       1000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | BBBBB    |       2000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | BBBBB    |       2000 |
| 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | BBBBB    |       2000 |
+---------------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add  the query you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT t.timestamp, t.deviceid, coalesce(eventcount, 0)
FROM foo
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT timestamp, deviceid
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM foo ) AS d
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT min(timestamp), max(timestamp) FROM foo ) AS ts
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(ts.min, ts.max, '10m') AS gs(timestamp)
) AS t
ON foo.deviceid = t.deviceid
AND foo.timestamp = t.timestamp
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

In the first run we generate a table with this

```
SELECT timestamp, deviceid
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM foo ) AS d
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT min(timestamp), max(timestamp) FROM foo ) AS ts
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(ts.min, ts.max, '10m') AS gs(timestamp)
```

This table we generate looks like this

```
      timestamp      | deviceid 
---------------------+----------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | AAAAA
 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | AAAAA
 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | AAAAA
 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | AAAAA
 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | AAAAA
 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | AAAAA
 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | BBBBB
 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | BBBBB
 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | BBBBB
 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | BBBBB
 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | BBBBB
 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | BBBBB
(12 rows)
```

It has all the time-ranges needed. Then we RIGHT-OUTER join it.

The end result looks like this

```
      timestamp      | deviceid | coalesce 
---------------------+----------+----------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | AAAAA    |     1000
 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | AAAAA    |        0
 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | AAAAA    |        0
 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | AAAAA    |     1000
 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | AAAAA    |     1000
 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | AAAAA    |        0
 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | BBBBB    |     2000
 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | BBBBB    |     2000
 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | BBBBB    |        0
 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | BBBBB    |        0
 2017-01-01 00:40:00 | BBBBB    |        0
 2017-01-01 00:50:00 | BBBBB    |     2000
(12 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Left join` is OK but you are missing one field.

You need to include `DeviceID` in your generated series and then `left join` on the two fields.
`DeviceID` is hardcoded but can be pulled from a table.
Start and stop series parameters also hardcoded.

Query to use in left join:

```
select a.ts, unnest(array['AAAAA', 'BBBBB']) deviceid from 
generate_series('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-01 00:50:00', '10 minutes'::interval) a(ts)
```

**Update**
Make query gather data from table instead of hardcode it.

```
select s.ts, d.deviceid 
  from generate_series((select min(ts) from cte_data), (select max(ts) from cte_data), '10 minutes'::interval) s(ts)
  cross join (select distinct deviceid from cte_data) d
```

Full query (*modified*):

```
with cte_data(ts, deviceid, eventcount) as (

values
( '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp , 'AAAAA'    ,       1000 ),
( '2017-01-01 00:30:00' , 'AAAAA'    ,       1000 ),
( '2017-01-01 00:40:00' , 'AAAAA'    ,       1000 ),
( '2017-01-01 00:00:00' , 'BBBBB'    ,       2000 ),
( '2017-01-01 00:10:00' , 'BBBBB'    ,       2000 ),
( '2017-01-01 00:50:00' , 'BBBBB'    ,       2000 )

)
, cte_generated_full_timeseries as(
select s.ts, d.deviceid 
  from generate_series((select min(ts) from cte_data), (select max(ts) from cte_data), '10 minutes'::interval) s(ts)
  cross join (select distinct deviceid from cte_data) d
)

select t1.ts, t1.deviceid, coalesce(t2.eventcount, 0) eventcount from cte_generated_full_timeseries t1
left join cte_data t2 on (t1.ts = t2.ts and t1.deviceid = t2.deviceid)
order by deviceid, ts
```